# Transfering database from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, import, export

My old hard disk have a problem that I can't use it now and my database is currently still on it. How can I copy my database by connecting my old hard to my new laptop ?

Like excel that have a file for each database .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to locate the various database files on your old hard disc. There will be a minimum of one data file (`*.mdf`) and one log file (`*.ldf`). Then copy them over and attach them using SSMS (Right click the "Databases" node in object explorer and choose the "Attach" option in the context menu).

Comment: thanks for the answer martin . but where is the DB files ? Where are they stored  Please give me an address like c:/programfiles/...

Comment: Probably `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\SomeFolderName\MSSQL\DATA\`

Comment: just do a search for *.mdf and *.ldf.